# Plotting lines, alphas and facet_grids

Tags: ggplot2

I'd like to compare a number of curves which are very similar.  Plotting them on the same axis gets very confusing (because they are so close together) but plotting them on different axes is no better because they are almost indistinguishable.

I'd like to do a `facet_wrap` for each curve and have the curves which do not belong to that facet set to `alpha = 0.25` while the faceted curve is `alpha = 1`.

For reference, my data looks like

```
tibble::tribble(
        ~METHOD,    ~mean,            ~lower,            ~upper,             ~width,   ~n,          ~p,
   "ASYMPTOTIC", 0.939365, 0.938319047477885, 0.940410952522115, 0.0445455136166802, 500L,  "p = 0.07",
      "CLOGLOG", 0.946005, 0.945005622467146, 0.946986730333604, 0.0445611267179592, 500L,  "p = 0.07",
        "EXACT", 0.964695, 0.963876926502612,  0.96549956881645, 0.0465924279807666, 500L,  "p = 0.07",
        "LOGIT",  0.95672, 0.955819372211766, 0.957603082736301, 0.0450897716879822, 500L,  "p = 0.07",
       "WILSON",  0.95672,  0.95581938978958, 0.957603065836674,  0.044862320426846, 500L,  "p = 0.07",
   "ASYMPTOTIC",  0.93936, 0.938314007137612, 0.940405992862388, 0.0445885063907574, 499L,  "p = 0.07"
  )
```

I'd like to facet `METHOD` and plot `n` vs `width`.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't do much with your sample data (need more rows), so I cooked up an example using some generated data. Basically, if we add two grouping variables, we can add the lines to each facet and control the alpha, and then use the normal facetting.

Basically, I would add a second column `METHOD2` (which equals `METHOD`), and use that to draw lines on each facet. In the call to `geom_line` using `METHOD2`, make sure to specify `geom_line(data = select(dat, -METHOD), aes(group = METHOD2))`

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
dat <- data_frame(x = rnorm(50),
                  y = 2 * x + rnorm(50),
                  g = sample(letters[1:3], 50, T))
dat$g2 <- dat$g

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_line(data = select(dat, -g),
            aes(group = g2), alpha = .25)+
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~g)
```

[image]

---

Specific code for your case:

```
dat$METHOD2 <- dat$METHOD

ggplot(dat, aes(x = width, y = n))+
 geom_line(data = select(dat, -METHOD), aes(group = METHOD2), alpha = 0.25)+
 geom_line()
```

Comment: Amazing, just as I had envisioned it.  Thanks for all your help!